# how to convert blob data to downloadable excel/CSV file in react js

Tags: excel, reactjs, blob

**i am getting a blob from the Get API** [image: click here to see the format]
with response shown here [image: response]
logic to create file like so after getting the response.

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' }))
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.innerText = 'Open the array URL';
      link.setAttribute('download', 'myExcel.xlsx');
      link.click();
```

its creating corrupted excel file.

Answer (score 2):

create headers like this

```js
const headers = {Accept: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",};
```

and the your request in axios

```js
Axios.get("my-api/stream", { responseType: 'blob',headers });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) package.

Comment: blob picture is there attached in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
saveAs(new Blob([result], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}), 'myExcel.xlsx');
```